# How to connect usb webcam to ev3?

Tags: image-processing, labview, robotics, lego-mindstorms

I would like to connect an USB webcam to my EV3.
is it possible to do that?

and how can I do it and how can I reach the cam from my code?

I use Labview for programming

and thanks in advance :)

Comment: According to the [specs I found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Mindstorms_EV3) you should be able to since you've got a little linux box and a usb host port. I don't own one, so not what linux packager manager it comes with, but perhaps opkg is support in which case you can install a driver. Note that the CPU has only 300MHz so in terms doing computer vision it must be pretty low res.

Comment: [ev3dev](http://www.ev3dev.org/) looks like something you should look into. It should allow install a driver and use a programming language of your choice to stream the webcam image over udp to labview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [leJOS](http://lejos.org) and [ev3dev](http://www.evdev.org) support USB web cams connected to the EV3 brick, however, neither work with LabView.

To get this working on the official LEGO firmware, you need to compile proper kernel modules, sideload them on the EV3 and as suggested in the comments, sideload another program that converts the image data into something that can communicate with labview remotely.

Answer (score 0):

use bellow vi to convert image to 2d array use array tool to cut appropriate part 
and do not forget for average use this equation otherwise the answer will be wrong
ave=r/3  +  b/3  +g/3   not  r+b+g/3
[vi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N111v.png)